# HEALTH CHECK not resolving for ClamAV hosted in GKE cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, healthcheck, yaml, ingress

Couldn't resolve health check related issue for the clamAV:1.2 deployment hosted in the GKE cluster in the port 3310,  7357.

> Facing some backend services are in UNHEALTHY state, in the ingress after adding routing path to the service defined.

I've deployed a clamAV:1.2 docker image in the GKE cluster through **deployment file.**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: clam-av
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: clam-av
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: clam-av
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool: XXX-XXX-pool
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
      - name: clamav-container
        image: clamav/clamav:1.2
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 200m
            memory: 1Gi
        imagePullPolicy: Always       
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3310
        # - containerPort: 7357
```

Created a **service file** for this deployment:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: clam-av-service
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default": "backend-for-clamAV"}'
spec:
  selector:
    run: clam-av
  ports:
  - name: http3310
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 3310
  # - name: http7357
  #   protocol: TCP
  #   port: 80
  #   targetPort: 7357
  type: ClusterIP
```

Also created a **BackendConfig:**

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: backend-for-clamAV
spec:
  timeoutSec: 150
  connectionDraining:
    drainingTimeoutSec: 150
  healthCheck:
    checkIntervalSec: 15
    port: 80
    type: HTTP
    requestPath: /
    healthyThreshold: 1
    unhealthyThreshold: 3
    timeoutSec: 15
```

Tried setting the spec.healthcheck.type as TCP as  the clamAV 3310 is a TCP connection. But the GCP ingress doesn't supports TCP.

Any suggestion to resolve this issue would be appreciated. Thank You !